# How to change api return result in asp.net core 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

My requirement is when the return type of the action is void or Task, I'd like to return my custom `ApiResult` instead. I tried the middleware mechanism, but the response I observed has null for both ContentLength and ContentType, while what I want is a json representation of an empty instance of `ApiResult`.
Where should I make this conversion then?

Comment: You create your custom class object and return it at the last line of your API action method.

Comment: I don't want to repeat that in every action method. I just want the action method to return void. This could be achieved in web api 2 via a custom DelegatingHandler, because even a void or Task returning action would generate a HttpResponseMessage result which I can manipulate.

Comment: It sounds like an [Action Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#action-filters) would be appropriate here.

Comment: Worth pointing out that If the actions do any async work.. it shouldn't return `void`.

Comment: @jpgrassi thanks for pointing out. I'm aware of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple filter in .net core, and you could try [Result filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#result-filters).

For `void` or `Task`, it will return `EmptyResult` in `OnResultExecutionAsync`.

Try to implement your own `ResultFilter` like

```
public class ResponseFilter : IAsyncResultFilter
{
    public async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // do something before the action executes
        if (context.Result is EmptyResult)
        {
            context.Result = new JsonResult(new ApiResult());
        }
        var resultContext = await next();
        // do something after the action executes; resultContext.Result will be set
    }
}
public class ApiResult
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public object Result { get; set; }
}
```

And register it in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddScoped<ResponseFilter>();
services.AddMvc(c =>
                {                       
                    c.Filters.Add(typeof(ResponseFilter));
                }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Comment: May I ask something furthermore? Do registered result filters and output formatters both work in a way that they will be executed in order regardless, instead of short-circuiting the rest in the registered list, as long as there's no exception during the pipeline execution?

Comment: One thing to note is that if the action returns void, the output formatters won't be called at all.

Comment: @Nico Do you mean after adding `ResponseFilter`, the `output formatter` is not called?

Comment: Nah, I meant when there were no conversion from void to my own ApiResult in the result filter. So simply using output formatters only is not enough.

Comment: One more thing, the ContentLength is never set though. Don't know which object should be responsible for setting this value.

Comment: I could not get this working properly, because any changes I would make to the resultContext.Result would not be send back in the api response. I got it working by using IAlwaysRunResultFilter in stead, and then OnResultExecutionAsync.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to check the return type and on the basis of the return you can perform whatever operations you want.

Here is the abstract demo: 
You have a method:

```
 public Action SomeActionMethod()
    {
        var obj = new object();
        return (Action)obj;
    }
```

Now in your code you can use the following code to get the name of the method:

```
 MethodBase b = p.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault();
        var methodName = ((b as MethodInfo).ReturnType.Name);
```

Where p in the above code is the class which contains the methods whose return type you want to know.

after having the methodname you can decide on variable `methodName` what to return.

Hope it helps.